# Ember Simple Auth intergration with djoser (django rest framework)

Tags: django, authentication, ember.js

I would like to ask if it's a good practice to use [ember simple auth](http://ember-simple-auth.com/) library with [djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser). I am using ember for frontend and I would like to use a certain backend made in django.
I was wondering if it's better to use ember simple auth library or to try to implement authentication from scratch. I just don't know in what level djoser implements login/logout actions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider a good practice to use ember simple auth with anything. It's a good and ready solution. Maybe you will need to implement authenticator and authorizer, but it's faster than writing and debugging the whole auth from the scratch.